# Creating a holomorphic map from a three holed torus to a two holed torus.

Tags: riemann-surfaces

I'm trying to make a non-constant holomorphic map, $f$, between a 3 holed torus and a 2 holed torus, with no branch points.

Now I can see that $deg(f) = 2$ from the Riemann Hurwitz formula. So intuitively, I want to treat the three holed torus as two tori attached with handles and then have a 2-1 map from this surface into a 2 holed torus.

I'm having trouble actually writing down this map. Is there a nice way to embed a three holed torus? Analogously to how we can write a torus as $T = S^1 x S^1$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$

Thanks

Comment: Your title suggests you want a holomorphic map, but your first sentence says non-holomorphic. Which is it?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to write non-constant in the post. I'm looking for a holomorphic map

Answer (score 0):

Picture the standard depiction of $\Sigma_3$, where the three holes are in a row. Note that this surface has 180-degree rotational symmetry, i.e. $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ acts on it. Also note that this action is free (i.e. neither element of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ fixes any point of $\Sigma_3$) and each orbit is discrete. As such, we can consider the quotient of $\Sigma_3$ by this action. This quotient turns out to be $\Sigma_2$, which we find by picturing the "right half" of $\Sigma_3$. There is a hole (the rightmost hole), and the right half is bound by two loops, which, when we pass to the quotient, are glued together, making another hole.

This construction generalizes to give a holomorphism $\Sigma_{mn+1} \to \Sigma_{m+1}$ for any nonnegative integers $m, n$.

Comment: This ideed gives a $2$-sheeted **topological** covering map $\Sigma_3\rightarrow \Sigma_2$ (see Example 1.41 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*). If you start with a complex structure on $\Sigma_3$, this moreover endows the quotient space $\Sigma_3/(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\cong\Sigma_2$ with a complex structure, making the quotient map $\pi\colon \Sigma_3\rightarrow \Sigma_2$ holomorphic (c.f. page 78 in Miranda's *Algebraic Curves and Riemann surfaces*). However, there are many complex structures on $\Sigma_2$…

Comment: In other words, if you fix arbitrary complex structures on $\Sigma_3$ and $\Sigma_2$, then I am not sure that the above construction generally yields a **holomorphic** map $\Sigma_3\rightarrow \Sigma_2$.